# TypeScript source maps in Firefox console?

Tags: firefox, typescript, console, source-maps, firefox-developer-edition

Is it possible to see TypeScript source maps in console?

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition and the Console is showing the .js line-numbers. I have a single .js file, compiled from multiple TypeScript files.

Chrome and Safari are showing the TypeScript sources correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to deal with this problem. I found an answer that works for me and have detailed it in an answer here [Firefox isnt showing typescript ts source maps in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390087/firefox-isnt-showing-typescript-ts-source-maps-in-the-debugger/38874167#38874167)

Your problem looks similar. Fundamentally it seems because FF does not handle relative paths to the .map files which are specified in your compiled javascript.

Comment: In principle, Firefox does handle relative paths to .map files, but there is an issue in conjunction with SystemJS. I have not fully grasped the issue, but you may want to have a look at these links: 
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/820, 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1224078, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223439

Comment: As a workaround, you may want to set "mapRoot" to something like "http://localhost:3000/app/" in tsconfig.json.