# Debugging typescript in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, debugging, firefox

I use Node for running the Angular 2 application, .map files are generated fine...using systemjs as well.
Everything is really simple and ordinary, but when I go to Firefox and try to debug any of .ts files, it reports:

"Not found: file "/dist/login.service.ts" in package systemjs@0.19.27".

I checked .map files and they are fine, .js files also have the comment line pointing to a .map file....this does not work neither in Firebug nor in the native FF debugger.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here, maybe works for you. FF dislikes relative paths to your .map files. If you are using Gulp I have included my Gulp task which creates absolute paths for the .map files. For me it is working now in both Chrome and Firefox.

[Firefox isnt showing typescript ts source maps in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390087/firefox-isnt-showing-typescript-ts-source-maps-in-the-debugger/38874167#38874167)